# Ruby Get Array From Objects Returned in a Block

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, block

In Ruby, on certain occasions (ruby/gosu/texplay) I'v seen code like the following used:

```
image.paint {
    circle 20, 20
    pixel 10, 10
}
```

Would it be possible for me to write a similar function that can be used like so?:

```
my_function {
    "one"
    "two"
    "three"
}
```

that would return and array:
    ["one", "two", "three"]

p.s. this function isn't just for generating arrays and I am not wondering about methods to do so, all I need to know about is the syntax. Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TexPlay` looks nice, how do you find it? :)

I can't think of a way to do what you want, sorry. But if you prefix every string with `_` it is easy:

```
function {
    _"one"
    _"two"
    _"three"
}

#=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Where:

```
def function(&block)
    Object.new.tap do |s| 
        s.instance_eval do            
            def _(var)
                @val ||= []
                @val << var
            end
        end
        s.instance_eval(&block)
     end.instance_variable_get(:@val)
end
```

Comment: I found it in the Gosu forums :) I use Gosu because its the simplest 2d library for Ruby I could find! Thanks for this example, its brilliant and tells me what I need to know. Thanks again